# Can't use Git Pages

Tags: html, github, deployment

TLDR: GitHub Pages isn't working.
I have a little knowledge on GitHub and tried multiple fixes to no avail. One repository is only showing readme file contents.
Please explain in lamest terms.

New to web development, I finally was able to complete my first site, but I'm unable to actually deploy the files for some reason; please forgive me, I literally have no idea what any of the git terminologies are.

I purchased a pro subscription in order to keep the repository private and the site public.
Every file is present in what seems to be the main root directory, but nothing is being actually presented.

I've created two different repositories in an effort to fix this, as I've seen different methods are available.

- The first repository includes a `README` file because I was originally instructed to do so, however, all the site link does is present that README file's contents;
  I also attempted to add a permalink fix within the file, but all it did was add that text to the other text presented.
- The second repository in question literally greets me with nothing but a 404 error.
  The solution I tried for the second repository was to have the repository name share my username as well since that seems to be where the site's link originates, but no present changes have occurred.

Finally, the waiting game solution hasn't beared any fruit yet either aside from updating the `README` file's contents.
All help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Quick edit for more information: I noted that the site is static, but it's 6 different HTML documents. I believe the issue may be in how to present what Git should be displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have GitHub Pages enabled for every repository and that it's set to the branch you want to publish by checking your Pages settings at `github.com/<user>/<repo>/settings/pages`. If enabled, there should be a link on that page that takes you to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Check first:

- Your GitHub repository name, which depends on the [type of GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site) you are creating

> If you're creating a user or organization site, your repository must be named `<user>.github.io` or `<organization>.github.io`.

- your [GitHub Pages Publishing source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

> If you use the default publishing source for your GitHub Pages site, your site will publish automatically. You can also choose to publish your site from a different branch or folder.
>
> You can add more pages to your site by creating more new files.
> Each file will be available on your site in the same directory structure as your publishing source.
>
> For example, if the publishing source for your project site is the `gh-pages` branch, and you create a new file called `/about/contact-us.md` on the `gh-pages` branch, the file will be available at `https://<user>.github.io/<repository>/about/contact-us.html`.

Comment: Try and follow https://guides.github.com/features/pages/ just for testing